# Zipping tuples inside Haskell tree

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, binary-search-tree

I'm seeking any suggestion how to solve a problem with a binary search tree in Haskell. It has declaration as follows:

```
data TreeMap v = Leaf | Node { pair::(Integer, v), l::TreeMap v, r::TreeMap v} deriving (Show, Read, Eq, Ord)
```

Now I want to zip all pairs to have them as array elements. My solution so far is

```
listMyTuples :: TreeMap v -> [(Integer, v)]
listMyTuples Leaf = []
listMyTuples (Node pair Leaf tree2) = pair : listMyTuples tree2
listMyTuples (Node pair tree1 Leaf) = pair : listMyTuples tree1
...other pattern matching needed
```

I'm barely to complete that due to some lack of comprehension what to do in a case of missing leafs. So, how to make some kind of functional brigde between two subtrees to get it right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why pattern match on the subtrees? You can just use `Node pair t1 t2`. Indeed:

```
listFromTree :: TreeMap v -> [(Integer, v)]
listFromTree Leaf = []
listFromTree (Node pair t1 t2) = pair : listFromTree t1 ++ listFromTree t2
```

Here we use [**`(++) :: [a] -> [a] -> [a]`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:-43--43-) to append two lists together.

In case one of the two subtrees is a `Leaf`, then this will result in an empty list, and appending with an empty list, results in the other list.

Comment: Haskell is fine as your answer, indeed. Absolutely, now things look well. Many thanks